# How can we securely store an access token in storage with the help of Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

We want to implement a fingerprint authentication for that we want to store the access token in the device storage.

1. how can we store it securely ? Ionic vault is one option but it is paid.
   We are looking for open source alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [secure storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage) plugin. Check the [github repo](https://github.com/mibrito707/cordova-plugin-secure-storage-echo) for more details on the security implementations.